Audi A4 8d 1.9 TDI AVG
Hello I have an Audi A4 1999 that only work ac with coolant temp unplugged the sensor it's new and original no DTC ac is charged pressure sensor ok I find that in ecu motor temp is ok rise normal and works fine ... But entering in the HVAC  with vag con the ac off status  parameter is showing 11 = Compressor OFF: Engine Temperature too high (> 118 °C). Wich we can confirm because it shows 121
Then when I unplug coolant temp. The ac clutch automatically engage and fan works all system works fine. Plug sensor ac clutch stops work no ac in HVAC temp goes to 121 °c on ecu temperatures all ok I already tested a climatronic  a ac pressure valve by passed it to and to original temp sensor a friend sad me that the car has 2 sensor I don't think so couldn't find it. Other ting in climatronic "secret menu " I can see 2 motor temperatures one  is the reading of ecu ok other is 121 Which I don't know what it is can someone help me

What is your Audi's thermostat temperature rating? 88C? 90C? 188C may be correct insofar as the coolant sensor measuring coolant temps. However, if the t-stat is operating below or higher than rated, this can affect engine operating conditions and other systems. Either use a hand held infrared temperature reader on the coolant sensor area, measure radiator temps, etc, to determine if the t-stats is operating within its rating. Other temperature sensors; air intake and ambient air. Some engines may have oil and/or transmission temperature sensors.

@FDryer  This generation of TDI has 2 independent sensors (4 wires) in the one coolant temp sensor. One sensor is for the temp gauge in the dash, the other sensor is for coolant temp data for the ECU.
